# GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths taking lot of time

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to get the all paths between two nodes.But it is taking lot of time(more than 1 hour).
I am using  GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths api .

Can anybody suggest is there way other api which gives all paths faster.

After getting all paths, I need to iterate through each path and need to filter them based on node filter and relationship filter.

Answer (score 0):

What's your estimated lengths of the returned paths between these nodes? Do you filter as much as you can in terms of relationship types / direction in the expander you pass in?

Comment: length can be any and i need to apply filter on node and relationships

Comment: I need to pass direction to relationship as wel